# Status of Internal websites by using PING

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

Afternoon All,

Just after a bit of advice on the best method to use for the following.

I am new ish to .net and have an Asp.net web page in development that i simply lists some internal web sites by a ping command and outlines their status (on-line / offline).  This is current;y activated by the click of a button.

I need to set up this developemt web page so that it automatically runs at a specific time on a morning say 7am for arguments sake and to then notify a user group by email the status of these items.

I have used Microsoft Visual studio (VB) 2010 before and can create simple web works that connect/ extract/ update data to and from SQL 2008.  I have also had some experience in creating scheduled jobs in SQL but not much.

I thought i could maybe create a scheduled job in SQL 2008, find a way to populate the data into the database, use this data in my website and display it a gridview or something.  And either have the SQL job or the website email a group of users the status of these internal web sites.

Does anyone know if i would beable to complete the above just in .net?  Am i able to write a script of some sort or schedule the web page to run at a specified time?

Im not 100% sure on the best method to tackle this job and i have limited experience.  Can anyone suggest any best method ideas on how to complete the above.

Regards
Bet.

Comment: Do you want to know whether the servers are online, or if the web sites are available? They are not the same thing and the ping will only tell you about the servers, not the web sites.

Comment: Hi Fredrik many thanks for your help.  The current btnPing_click that i have has just been tested on two of our site that are located on our production box and it simply uses the IP address of that box to check to see if production is up or down.  Its a start in the right direction but really i should look look at finding a way to ping the individual web sites.  Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what your goal is here, but if your aim is simply to see if a server or application is running then you may want to look into existing systems management/monitoring applications rather than write your own from scratch. [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) is a very common one, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Although fairly trivial to implement, I don't believe a `ping` command is useful in the context of what you are trying to achieve.

As Fredrik pointed out, a ping only says that the server is available.  It makes no statement as to whether an individual website is functional on that server.

If I was doing this I would create a service that runs every so often.  The service would issue a get request to the web sites, do a little bit of parsing on the content to make sure what was returned was expected, and update a record in a database stating the time of the connection and the status (up/down).

For example:

```
public String CheckSite(String postLocation) {
    HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(postLocation);
    // Setting the useragent seems resolves certain issues that *may* crop up depending on the server
    httpRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";
    httpRequest.KeepAlive = false;
    httpRequest.Method = "GET";

    using ( HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse() ) {
        using ( StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()) ) {
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        } // using reader
    } // using httpResponse

    return result;
}
```

This simple call will load a page from a server.  From there you can parse to see if you have words like "error" or what have you.  Provided it looks good then you report back that the site is up.

I know the above is C#, but you should be able to easily convert that to VB if necessary.  You should also place a try .. catch around the call.  If it errors out then you know the server is completely offline.  If the page returns, but contains "error" or something then you know the server is up but the app is down.

Answer (score 0):

pesronally . . .  I think the most elegant solution would be: (untested)

```
public String CheckSite(String postLocation) {
    HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(postLocation);
    // Setting the useragent seems resolves certain issues that *may* crop up depending on the server
    httpRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727)";
    httpRequest.KeepAlive = false;
    httpRequest.Method = "GET";

    using ( HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse() ) {
       if(httpResponse.StatusCode != {check for valid status codes here})
```

{
//Do something based upon an invalid response.
}
        } // using httpResponse

```
    return result;
}
```